# Is it possible to make a persistent shopping cart in Opencart

Tags: php, opencart, cart

I want to make persistent shopping cart in a store powered by Opencart. In other words, If a user add products into shopping cart and user is not yet logined. But next time when customer visit site again within a week his products should be in his cart.

Products should be removed only when user explicitly removed products from cart or checkout or after one week.

I think this can be done by using cookies? help will be appreciated

Comment: someone should write a module for this! (maybe someone already did, have you checked to modules page?)

Comment: It depends how long you set the cookie to expire. You can't set it to stay infinitely, but you can set it to last until (I think) the end of epoch, which is 2037 or something. Also - users can delete their cookies, and/or edit them, meaning your best option is to probably store their cart details in a database and have the cookie with a unique token pointing to their details in the database.

Comment: I try to find some module but I didn't find any.

Answer (score 3):

There's a VERY EASY WAY to do this.

This modification works with OC 1.4.X.X and OC 1.5.X.X

Here's how it's done:

In the home directory, find system/library/session.php

You will find a line that reads:

session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');

For a 24-hour cookie, change the line to:

session_set_cookie_params(60*60*24, '/');

You're multiplying the number of seconds in a minute by the number of minutes in an hour by the number of hours in a day, that you want to set the cookie to.

This is not a true persistent cookie, but rather a very long session cookie, and as Jay Gilford has pointed out, there's no [easy] way to create persistent cookies with OpenCart, and if we figure out a way to do this we will let you all know. And because OpenCart treats this cookie as a session cookie, no matter how long the session, it will not automatically update the cookie with a new expiration date so long as the cookie has not yet expired.

A harmless side effect of the extend session cookie is that when you log in to the administrator page without previously having logged out, you'll be greeted with an "invalid token" message. It's because the (extended) session cookie "remembers" your last administrator log in. Just ignore this and log in. There's another drawback though, which is that if there's a product price change, and a user has already added that product to the basket, the user will have the former price stored in the 24-hour cookie.

The reason why OpenCart is built like this appears to be the privacy laws of the European Union, which prohibit persistent cookies unless a registered user has not logged out. Many e-commerce websites using Opencart in the United States and Canada are being needlessly burdened by a hardwired cookie policy that is causing them to lose customers who return to their websites, only to have to do their ordering all over again.

Comment: While this solution does "work" in the sense that it makes the cart persistent it should be noted that this will make the entire session persistent, which may not be desirable

Answer (score 1):

There is no mod that will do this in opencart. As mentioned in the comments section, your best option is to use cookies with a token or set the session expiry to last as long as 7 days (though this has it's drawbacks)

Comment: Is it true for a registered user also? If A registered user adds products in his cart?

Comment: @SyedMudabbir No, a registered user that is logged in will have their cart saved

Comment: Oh my registered customers complain all the time even after saving to the cart after logging in, it never saves the items for more than few hours.

Comment: @SyedMudabbir Unless you have modified the cart to do so, that won't be possible. The cart is saved to the database for the user (they need to log in to see their previously saved items in the cart)

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
session_set_cookie_params(60*60*24, '/');
```

It **should** be:

```
session_set_cookie_params(time() + 60*60*24, '/');
```

Anyway, this modifies the core file (system/library/session.php), so really not a perfect solution.

Comment: You can use that horrible modified cache thing called VQmod (or OCmod in later versions) rather than modifying the actual files.

Edit: also you're wrong about needing time(); it is the number of seconds, not the time it expires. Please see http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Comment: Yes, but `session_set_cookie_params` does not extends the cookie lifetime after refresh, so removing the `time()` will make the cart **not** permanent. See: [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php#100657)

Answer (score -1):

Please see the next comment for the solution.